# What is Product Scope for Custom Dimensions in Google Universal

Tags: ios, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm setting up a new Custom Dimension in my Google Universal account.

I know about the Hit, User, and Session scopes, but today I saw a new one: Product.

What is that and how do we use it? [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets) only discusses the other three types of scope, but I'm interested in what exactly a Product scope is and how we use it within the Google Analytics dashboard.

Comment: If I had to take a guess, I'd say it's a custom dimension you set during an ecommerce event (e.g. [`ec:addProduct`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-detail-view)) and it gets bound to the product (as opposed to a page view or across a visit) so for example you can use it as a 2ndary dimension of a product but not page or some other random dimension. That's my guess anyways.. looks like google made a new thing and are slow on the documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Product scope is for Custom Dimensions involved in the new [Enhanced eCommerce](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014841) feature.

You can read the solution article in and [Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-product).